# Can't resize DIV with jquery after changing text inside the DIV

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui

I have a jquery function in my website that requires a DIV with changeable text to be editable, dragable and resizable, however, after I change the content of the DIV, the DIV loses the ability to be resized.
 I'm hoping someone can help me out, here is the code:

HTML

```
<form id="myform">
        <select id="fs"> 
        <option value="Arial">Arial</option>
        <option value="Verdana ">Verdana </option>
        <option value="Impact ">Impact </option>
        <option value="Comic Sans MS">Comic Sans MS</option>
    </select>

    <select id="size">
        <option value="7">7</option>
        <option value="10">10</option>
        <option value="20">20</option>
        <option value="30">30</option>
    </select>
</form>
<textarea id="txt" style="width:400px; height:100px;"></textarea>
<div id='test' >
    test
</div>
```

CSS

```
#test {
max-width: 360px;
max-height: 320px;
padding: 0;
z-index: 1000;
}
}
```

Jquery

```
$(function(){
  $('#txt').keyup(function(){
     $('#test').text($(this).val());
  });
});
$(function(){
    $("#test").resizable({
        maxHeight: 360,
        maxWidth: 320
    });
     $("#test").draggable();
});



$("#fs").change(function() {
    //alert($(this).val());
    $('#test').css("font-family", $(this).val());

});

$("#size").change(function() {
    $('#test').css("font-size", $(this).val() + "px");
});
```

Also a js fiddle of the full thing:
http://jsfiddle.net/JTVRZ/18/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problems is happening because when you modify the div contend you overwrite the resizable handle elements inside your div.

You can try to make another div with 100% width and height inside your resizable div to hold the content.

Answer (score 3):

Had the same issue, googling it brought me here, the above suggestion did not resolve my problem.

It did however point me in the right direction... i needed to destroy the original resizable reference on the control in order to re-instantiate it.

```
$('#MyContol').resizable('destroy');
$('#MyContol').text(newtext);
$('#MyContol').resizable({ containment: $('#MyContol').parent() });
```

Hopefully will help someone else with the issue.

Comment: The cursor will be stuck as one of the resize cursors if destroy occurs in the middle of a resize, so make sure you  `$('body').css("cursor", "")` after destroy...

Answer (score 0):

The resizable function adds some markup on your div (you can inspect it using firebug). When you replace the text, that markup is lost, so your div loses the ability to get resized. You should call the resizable function again after you change the text.